# Ordering \newtheorem and Resetting Each Subsection

Tags: newtheorem

This might be a simple question but I'm relatively new to LaTeX and couldn't find how to do this.

I want to number my `\newtheorem` through the natural numbers but resetting every subsection.

If I set it as:

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]
```

It orders it as `a.b.c` whereas I only want it as `c`.

Essentially I want examples to be ordered and reset each subsection.

Any solution would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Adding `\renewcommand{theexample}{\alph{example}}` to your preamble should be enough

Answer (score 2):

You can change the numbering style of some theorem `name` by renewing `\thename`. Here is a MWE for `example`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\alph{subsection}}

\begin{document}
    \subsection{This is the subsection}
    \begin{example}
        Here is the example.
    \end{example}

\end{document}
```

Other numbering styles are `\roman`, `\Roman`, `\arabic` and `\Alph`.
One can also mix these, e.g.

```
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\arabic{section}.\alph{subsection}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to redefine `\theexample`, after defining the environment to be a slave of `subsection`:

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\alph{example}}
```